# I've just applied SUPEE-9767 to a Magento 1.6.2.0 site and there is no formkey option to enable. How has this happened and how can I fix it please?

Tags: patches, security, magento-1.6, form-key, supee-9767

I have applied the `SUPEE-9767` patch for the correct version (1.6.2.0) of Magento and in the admin area, I can see the warning at the top of the page, indicating that the patch was successful.

[image]

However, when I navigate to the settings menu to enable the form-key option, it is not there.

[image]

I've cleared cache etc. and nothing seems to make the option visible. I've just updated about a dozen sites on different versions of Magento with no issues but this site is causing a huge problem. Can anyone help me to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout** not show in backend means `SUPEE-9767` not properly applied.

Please confirm that the below files are updated.

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. For some reason app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml had not been updated. Perfect, thanks again :)

Comment: Great  news  Any help based on Security patch please ask :)